# When the window is loading the event stops. After scrolling down the event starts

Tags: javascript, preventdefault, stoppropagation

```
(function () {
    var previousScroll = 0;

    $(window).scroll(function(){
    var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (currentScroll > previousScroll){
        
        event.preventDefault();
    } 
    previousScroll = currentScroll;
    });
}()); 


$(window).on('load', function () {
    $(".timer").timerstart({
        event.stopPropagation()l
    });
});
```

is it possible?
when the page is begin event is stopping and scroll down event start.